# Open terminal and it reads a line to me?

Tags: terminal

I know the settings were changed so that everytime I open my terminal it reads my name to me via the `say` command. Where is the file that it was saved in (so I can delete that line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `say` command has been added to one of your shell’s startup files. Try this command to search for the `say` command in all of them:

```
grep say ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login /etc/bashrc /etc/profile
```

If that doesn’t turn anything up, you can run `sudo filebyproc.d` to start a trace of all files being access on the filesystem, open a new terminal, and look for which files are read by the `bash` command. The [filebyproc.d(1m) manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/filebyproc.d.1m.html) has more info if you’re forced to go down this route.